# Vim # expansion

Tags: vim, perforce

I am using vim and perforce on a daily basis

Now my problem is that from vim in command mode if i want to check out a perforce file revision

:!p4 print file#1

vim tries to get me the buffer #1. Is there a way to disable vim expansion

Any suggestions
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Escape the `#` with a backslash: `:!p4 print file\#1`

Comment: Use [`:help cmd-special`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-special) to see the documentation for `#` and other special “command line mode” characters/sequences.